# Why swagger jbpm documentation has been recently drastically reduced?

Tags: swagger, jbpm

Up to 1 month ago when I browsed http://localhost:8080/business-central/docs I got a long list of endpoints.

Now I get only a short list:
[image: current endpoints list]

while before it was much longer (and more useful), do you know how to obtain the full list again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you refer to kie-server APIs. They are under:
http://localhost:8080/kie-server/docs

Comment: yes exactly, for some reason in my notes on jbpm i marked http://localhost:8080/business-central/docs  as API docs, your link is what I was looking for, thank you!